# What is the best practise to relase Excel interop objects in C#?

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I have a function basically to convert an excel file to text file. The structure is like following. What I am concerned is the Finally part? Is it a best practise to kill the excel?

```
Excel.Application excel=new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook wb=excel.Workbooks.Open(…);

Try 
{
   …
   Foreach(Excel.Worksheet sheet in wb.Sheets)
   {
      …
      Marshal.RealseComObject(sheet);
   }
   …
}

Catch()
{
}

Finally
{
   wb.Close(false, missing, missing);
   while (Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wb)!=0)
   {
   }
   wb=null;
   excel.Quit();
   while (Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel)!=0)
   {
   }
   excel=null;
   GC.Collect();
   GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
}
```

Update:

I have following version of Finally

```
Finally{
wb.close(false, missing, missing);
excel.application.quit();
excel.quit();

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wb);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
}
```

Which one is better (make more sense)? I have checked all the links here, but there is no finally answer, everybody's answer is sightly difference. I am not sure which one is the best?

Comment: Or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926205/does-every-excel-interop-object-need-to-be-released-using-marshal-releasecomob) as well.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to call `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(object name)` or `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(object name)` on **all** of your `COM` objects.  Of course, depending on the *size* of your project, this can become unwieldy very quickly.  The code you have posted above should work just fine on a smaller scale and if you pay close attention to when/where your are creating the `COM` objects.  I found some further reading for you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects), [here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/showpost.php?s=f87f0674feda4442dcbd40019cbca65b&p=528575&postcount=2), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926205/does-every-excel-interop-object-need-to-be-released-using-marshal-releasecomob) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497250/excel-interop-com-doesnt-close).

Comment: Do I need to relase the excel.worksheet? Since I saw a few samples that don't release the worksheet in the foreach loop

Comment: @GLP - You _technically_ don't have to release them all, no.  But, if you are working with a large number of them, you really _should_.  They are considered 'unmanaged' as all things in the `interop` assemblies are.

Comment: So I think I should relase worksheet object. But in the foreach loop i couldn't set the sheet=null after the Marshal.RealseComObject(sheet). Does it mean I should not use foreach? Or I could creat a func like  private void NAR(object o)
    {
        try
        {
            while (System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(o) > 0) ;
        }
        catch { }
        finally
        {
            o = null;
        }
    } Then I could indirectly set the sheet object to null.