# Define Excel's column width with R

Tags: r, excel, csv, formatting

The final product is an Excel CSV spreadsheet which has more than 250 columns.
I was wondering if there was a way to determine the column width in Excel from R?

I am using write.csv2, which produces column width in excel all equal to 8,43.

> write.csv2(df, na = "", file= "Final.csv")

If possible I am looking for a trick to vary all of them at once or only specific ones.
Is [running VBA from R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404270/run-vba-script-from-r) my only option?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that at least one of the R-to-Excel packages will let you build xlsx spreadsheets that have column-level formatting options.

Comment: There's a conceptual problem with your question. Saving a file as `*.csv` by definition discards all the formatting information. So when you open such a file in Excel, you get Excel's default column widths. If you want to format, you must save as `*.xls` or `*.xlsx`.

Comment: Alternatively to the package `xlsx` mentioned in the accepted answer, you can use the `openxlsx` package. I prefer this one because it does not depend on `rJava`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Please check the package [xlsx](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/xlsx.pdf).   I am using it for generating excel files and its pretty good.  There is a method *setColumnWidth* which can help you.  Check [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/writing-from-r-to-excel-with-xlsx/) for more detailed example about xlsx package functionality.

---

So here is a working example using package `xlsx`.

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100),nc=10))
library(xlsx)
# must save as an xls or xlsx file...
write.xlsx(df,"Final.xlsx", row.names=FALSE)
# load it back
wb <- loadWorkbook("Final.xlsx")
sheets <- getSheets(wb)
# set widths to 20
setColumnWidth(sheets[[1]], colIndex=1:ncol(df), colWidth=20)
saveWorkbook(wb,"Final.xlsx")
# autosize column widths
autoSizeColumn(sheets[[1]], colIndex=1:ncol(df))
saveWorkbook(wb,"Final.xlsx")
```

Comment: Above code autoSizes single sheet depending on data frame we just added in that sheet, but how we can autosize all sheets from imported excel using above functionalities?

Answer (score 6):

A small improvement to the accepted answer: Writing a file just to read and modify it again is not very elegant.  Moreover, I had the experience that overwriting xls-files with `saveWorkbook` may lead to "corrupted" files (i.e. Excel will need to repair the file on opening it).

To avoid this, one can proceed as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100), nc=10))
library(xlsx)
wb <- createWorkbook(type = "xlsx")
sheet <- createSheet(wb, sheetName = "rnormdata")
addDataFrame(df, sheet, row.names = FALSE)
setColumnWidth(sheet, colIndex = 1:3, colWidth = 20)
autoSizeColumn(sheet, colIndex = 4:ncol(df))
saveWorkbook(wb, "Final.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define the column width when you write a file with `openxlsx`:

```
library(openxlsx)
openxlsx::write.xlsx(df, "C:/myfile.xlsx", sheetName = "Nice Sheet", rowNames = F, colWidths=30)
```

Comment: Similarly ,you could use `colWidths = "auto"`

Answer (score 0):

You can set a specific width for each column of your data set:

```
for(c in 1:ncol(yourData)){
setColumnWidth(sheetIndex,colIndex=c,colWidth=max(nchar(c(names(yourData[c],yourData[,c])))))
}
```