# Optimum way to overwrite an xlsx worksheet

Tags: r, excel, xlconnect

I'm trying to write an Excel worksheet with the `XLConnect` package. The data I'm using is a data.frame (820*132). Once I'm done building the dataset, I'm using the `writeWorksheetToFile` function to export.

If the file does **not** exist yet and I am creating it from scratch, everything works well.

If I want to **overwrite** an existing sheet, the function takes approximately a minute to write and in addition, when I open the **excel** file, I have an error message saying: `"we found a problem with some content in 'my_file.xlsx. Do you want to try to recover as much as we can?"`

I tried to use other packages to write to excel like `xlsx` and `openxlsx` but they do not allow to overwrite a sheet without overwriting the entire workbook.

I've checked a few solutions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34172353/how-do-i-modify-an-existing-a-sheet-in-an-excel-workbook-using-openxlsx-package/34242877), but I not optimal.

I am looking for the most optimal way of writing excel worksheets, with an overwrite option that is suitable for large datasets.

I'm using the latest versions of R and RStudio.

My Excel verion is 1902, 64bits.

Comment: Hello, it would be fine if you could provide a reproductible code ... t'is hard to help you not seing what code you wrote ..

Comment: Sorry, I edited my query. I am not really looking for a debug solution, more for advise on the best packages, methods to use.

Comment: So did you try anything with `officer` package ? Another thing you can pay attention to is the location of your existing excel file : is it on you local disk, or on a remote repository .. In the second case, it could be more longer to write on the file, than to copy it on your local disk, write in it from R and then copy it back to it's original location.