# What are the different ways to update an Excel sheet from R

Tags: r, excel, export

I am in the process of automating a number of graphs that are produced where I work through R that are currently in Excel.

Note that for now, I am not able to convince that doing the graphs directly in R is the best solution, so the solution cannot be "use ggplot2", although I will push for it.

So in the meantime, my path is to download, update and tidy data in R, then export it to an existing Excel file where the graph is already constructed.

The way I have been trying to do that is through `openxlsx`, which seems to be the most frequent recommendation (for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34172353/how-do-i-modify-an-existing-a-sheet-in-an-excel-workbook-using-openxlsx-package)).
However, I am encountering an issue taht I cannot solve with this way (I asked a question [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64756679/exporting-data-from-r-into-an-excel-file-that-contains-a-graphic-with-additional) that did not inspire a lot of answers !).

Therefore, I am going to try other ways, but I seem to mainly be directed to the aforementioned solution. What are the existing alternatives ?

Comment: Personally I use `writexl::write_xlsx` because it is very simple to use.  Perhaps you can write to an xlsx that only holds the data, and then make the graphic in a separate xlsx which references the cells in the first xlsx.

Comment: I will do the two files solution, even if not optimal. `writexl::write_xlsx` seems to only write a fil, not update it

Comment: Yes.  I suggest you read data from wherever, and then write to a clean output file.  Separate the stages of your workflow.