# Launch VBA macro from R

Tags: r, vba, excel, vbscript

I am currently trying to launch a very simple VBA macro from R. For that, I am following the procedure found here : [Run VBA script from R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404270/run-vba-script-from-r)
Unfortunately, when I open the Excel file after that, it's corrupted and Excel stops.
Here is my code :

**[r](/questions/tagged/r):**

```
library(XLConnect)
saveWorkbook(wb,pathfile)
# The saveWorkbook part is working
shell(shQuote(normalizePath(pathtovbs)), "cscript", flag = "//nologo")
```

---

**[vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript):**

```vb
Option Explicit
On Error Resume Next
ExcelMacroExample
Sub ExcelMacroExample() 
  Dim xlApp 
  Dim xlBook 
  Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
  Set xlBook =     xlApp.Workbooks.Open(pathfile, 0, True) 
  xlApp.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!MyMacro"
  xlApp.Quit 
  Set xlBook = Nothing 
  Set xlApp = Nothing 
End Sub
```

---

**[vba](/questions/tagged/vba) PESONAL.XLSB!MyMacro:**

```vb
Sub MyMacro()

 Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Sheets
       ws.Range("C:C").EntireColumn.Delete
       ws.Range("A:A").EntireColumn.Delete
   Next ws
End Sub
```

Do you have any idea what is going on ? I have checked the path of each file and they are good.
Thank you very much in advance.

**Edit :** Apparently, problem comes from the vbscript. The file opens but it can't find the macro located in my personal library (PERSONAL.XLSB). When I open Excel manually, I can access this macro, but when I open Excel from another program, I can't. Any idea why ?

Pauline

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: No, nothing. I just can't open it when it's done. Excel stops, ans when I can finally open the file, nothing has changed in it (the macro didn't work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. If some of you are trying to call personnal library from a vbscript, you need to add :

```
Dim objWorkbook
Set objWorkbook=xlApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\users\...\PERSONAL.XLSB")
```

before launching the macro.

Answer (score 1):

`pathfile` is not defined in your .vbs:

```
Set xlBook =     xlApp.Workbooks.Open(pathfile, 0, True)
```

and your EVIL

```
On Error Resume Next
```

hides all errors.

**Update wrt comment:**

("I added On Error Resume Next but now the file is empty") - You already **have** an EVIL OERN; you should remove it - and then study the error message - probably concerning the parameters to the `.Open` call.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. pathfile is hardcoded in the vbscript. I changed it in the post so that you don't have the full path to read. I added On Error Resume Next but now the file is empty...

Comment: Oh yes, I see what you mean now. I get "Unknown execution error" (translated from French)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `xlApp.Quit` without saving and closing the Workbook first.

Add this:

```
xlBook.Save
xlBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Before:

```
xlApp.Quit
```

And remove `On Error Resume Next` to see errors.

Comment: `xlBook.Close SaveChanges:=False` will cause an error in VBScript.