# R How to create image files from Excel range

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

I am trying to find a way to take a snapshot of a given cell range within an Excel workbook, that has been created by openxlsx in R, and generate a picture file with that snapshot. I have seen many posts about how to insert pictures into Excel, and one post about how to create a snapshot/chart combo however no luck with a simple picture export. Is there an openxlsx code, or other R package, that can assist with this?

Comment: Maybe this would be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43095645/how-to-export-an-excel-sheet-range-to-a-picture-from-within-r

Comment: @Adam This is the question I saw that generates a picture/chart combo. It is close to what I am looking for however I don't have a need for the autogenerated chart attached to the image.

Comment: Do you need the formatting as in the spreadsheet - or is it enough to have the relevant data in a grid on your image?