# How to run a VBS script from R, while passing arguments from R to VBS

Tags: r, vbscript

Let's say I want to run a VBS script from R, and I want to pass a value from R to that script.

For example, in a simple file called 'Msg_Script.vbs', I have the code:

```
Dim Msg_Text

Msg_Text = "[Insert Text Here]"

MsgBox("Hello " & Msg_Text)
```

How do I run this script using R, while editing the parameters and/or variables in R? In the above script for instance, how would I edit the value of the `Msg_Text` variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way would be to pass the value as an [argument to the VBScript](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156618.aspx)

You'd write the VBS as follows:

```
Dim Msg_Text
Msg_Text = WScript.Arguments(0)
MsgBox("Hello " & Msg_Text)
```

And then you'd create a system command in R like this:

```
system_command <- paste("WScript",
                        '"Msg_Script.vbs"',
                        '"World"',
                        sep = " ")
system(command = system_command,
       wait = TRUE)
```

This approach matches the arguments by position.
If you wanted, you could use named arguments instead. This way, your VBS would look like this:

```vb
Dim Msg_Text
Msg_Text = WScript.Arguments.Named.Item("Msg_Text")
MsgBox("Hello " & Msg_Text)
```

And then you'd create a system command in R like this:

```
system_command <- paste("WScript",
                        '"Msg_Script.vbs"',
                        '/Msg_Text:"World"',
                        sep = " ")
system(command = system_command,
       wait = TRUE)
```

Comment: How do you choose in what excel file to run the vbs?

Comment: @AlvaroMorales this is referring to standalone VBS on Windows not VBA that is used in Office applications

Answer (score 3):

Here's a somewhat-hackish solution:

Read the lines from the vbs script into R (using `readLines()`):

```
vbs_lines <- readLines(con = "Msg_Script.vbs")
```

Edit the lines in R by finding and replacing specific text:

```
updated_vbs_lines <- gsub(x = vbs_lines,
                          pattern = "[Insert Text Here]",
                          replacement = "World",
                          fixed = TRUE)
```

Create a new VBS script using the updated lines:

```
writeLines(text = updated_vbs_lines,
           con = "Temporary VBS Script.vbs")
```

Run the script using a system command:

```
full_temp_script_path <- normalizePath("Temporary VBS Script.vbs")
system_command <- paste0("WScript ", '"', full_temp_script_path, '"')

system(command = system_command,
       wait = TRUE)
```

Delete the new script after you've run it:

```
file.remove("Temporary VBS Script.vbs")
```