# Add new row to existing Excel table with XLConnect's appendWorksheet function

Tags: r, excel

What I'm trying to achieve is to add a row from an object in `R` to a table that already exists in an `Excel` file (Read table as in "Excel's table").

With the following code I perfectly add the row to the existing table:

```
library(XLConnect)
setStyleAction(wb,XLC$"STYLE_ACTION.NONE")
wb <- loadWorkbook("test.xlsx")
appendWorksheet(wb, expense, sheet="expenses", header = FALSE)
saveWorkbook(wb)
```

The problem here is that I´ve got tons of other formulas in Excel using the references as `Expenses[@TDC]` for example. If I add the row, the values will not be part of the `Expenses` table automatically. Is that possible to do?

Comment: Did you mean to put `wb <- ...` before the `setStyleAction`?  That's the only way I can get your sample code to work

Comment: This is a tough one:  the obvious solution ought to involve encompassing your expenses in an Excel "Table" object, and having `XLConnect` append to it.  But `XLConnect` can only `readTable`;  it can't `writeTable`.  I have an (inelegant) solution involving VBA macros below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest writing a simple formula-copying macro into your spreadsheet.  You'd need to call it `test.xlsm` instead of `test.xlsx`, of course.  If your spreadsheet looked like this:

[image]

then your macro might look like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub MyMacro()
    Dim BottomRowOfData As Integer, BottomRowOfFormula As Integer, rowDiff As Integer

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("expenses")
        BottomRowOfData = .Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row
        BottomRowOfFormula = .Range("C1").End(xlDown).Row
        rowDiff = BottomRowOfData - BottomRowOfFormula

        If (rowDiff > 0) Then
            .Range("C" & BottomRowOfFormula).Copy
            Call .Range(.Range("C" & BottomRowOfFormula + 1), .Range("C" & BottomRowOfData)).PasteSpecial
        End If
    End With

    ' Save your work
    ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

You can invoke VBA macros from R, as per my answer to [this question on so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404270/run-vba-script-from-r).  For completeness, here's the code from that question:

```
library(RDCOMClient)

# Open a specific workbook in Excel:
xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open("C:\\TEMP\\test.xlsm")

# this line of code is only necessary if you want to see your spreadsheet getting updated:
xlApp[['Visible']] <- TRUE 

# Run the macro called "MyMacro":
xlApp$Run("MyMacro")

# Close the workbook and quit the app:
xlWbk$Close(FALSE)
xlApp$Quit()

# Release resources:
rm(xlWbk, xlApp)
gc()
```

Comment: Awesome job here. It could work smoothly, but the problem is that I can't add a macro to this particular file (because it is used in devices with no macros possibilities). Obviously your answer is a totally valid way to do the job. Hope someday they add this "function" to the library as I'm sure it will be so useful for many.

Comment: Hmm.  Short of figuring out how to do more complex, macro-like Excel manipulations in R, maybe you can write some VBA macros in a "master" `.xlsm` workbook which manipulates all the other, non-macro-enabled `.xlsx` workbooks?