# saveWorkbook() from openxlsx package is not properly saving the workbook

Tags: r, tidyverse, openxlsx

I am trying to fill some columns based on a formula. I wrote the formula, ran the code and saved the workbook by calling **saveWorkbook()** function. When I open the excel to have a look everything seems fine. But when I read the data from the same sheet I am getting NAs for the columns that I filled earlier with formula.

Here is a simple example. Initially I have two columns: a and b

```
read.xlsx("data/rough.xlsx", sheet = "Sheet1", rows = c(1:4), cols = c(2,3))

  a  b
1 1 NA
2 2 NA
3 3 NA
```

I loaded the workbook and did the required changes

```
wb <- loadWorkbook("data/rough.xlsx")
formula_vector <- c(paste0("B", seq(2,4), "*2"))
writeFormula(wb, sheet = "Sheet1", x = formula_vector, startCol = 3, startRow = 2)
saveWorkbook(wb, "data/rough.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

After saving the workbook I ran the same line and got the same output

```
read.xlsx("data/rough.xlsx", sheet = "Sheet1", rows = c(1:4), cols = c(2,3))

  a  b
1 1 NA
2 2 NA
3 3 NA
```

this is what I actually have inside the sheet

[image]

Now I that I manually opened the file it is asking me whether to save or not even though I didn't change anything. If I save it and the run the same line in R...I am getting the correct values.

after manually saving the file

```
read.xlsx("data/rough.xlsx", sheet = "Sheet1", rows = c(1:4), cols = c(2,3))

  a b
1 1 2
2 2 4
3 3 6
```

How can I resolve this? It seems like even after running the **saveWorkbook()** R is still holding some details of that workbook.

Please let me know if you come across any solutions. Thank you!

Comment: Not sure whether there is a solution. From the `Details` section of `?read.xlsx`: `Formulae written using writeFormula to a Workbook object will not get picked up by read.xlsx(). This is because only the formula is written and left to be evaluated when the file is opened in Excel. Opening, saving and closing the file with Excel will resolve this.`

Comment: Can you provide the Excel for which there is a problem? That would be helpful to replicte your problem

Comment: if that's the case, can i do that **opening**, **saving** and **closing** in R itself? I didn't provide file because it's a simple df with two columns. I thought it wouldn't take much time to create that file.

Answer (score 1):

The answer @[stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12993861/stefan) provided is the correct one. In addition to this, there are a few issues regarding this in the `openxlsx` bug tracker, see [here](https://github.com/ycphs/openxlsx/issues/261) or [here](https://github.com/ycphs/openxlsx/issues/188).

The problem basically boils down to how the xlsx file format works. If we write the formula `SUM(A2:A3)` from `openxlsx` we create a cell like this:

```
<c r="A1">
   <f>SUM(A2:A3)</f>
</c>
```

Once the file is opened in spreadsheet software like Excel, LibreOffice or Numbers, the formula gets evaluated. If the sum of `A2` and `A3` is `2`, the cell will become something like this:

```
<c r="A1">
   <f>SUM(A2:A3)</f>
   <v>2</v>
</c>
```

This is why Excel asks you to save the file, because once the file was loaded, the value was updated.

If the file is saved, the value can be read in `openxlsx` and other programs and packages that simply evaluate `v` node of a cell (AFAIK all R libraries do so). The only way to circumvent this, would be to implement a library that evaluates the formula and calculates the value. Or to use a headless libreoffice to evaluate the formula for you and save their output.

Why isn't the formula evaluated in R? Well for `SUM` this might be a simple task, but Excel has a few other functions that are custom to Excel and the implementation is not straight forward, even if you ignore things like different rounding or linked workbooks. Therefore I guess it is unlikely that someone will work on this.

On a side note, not even Excel evaluates formulas all the time. With linked workbooks, I've seen that the `v` node was picked unless the linked workbook was open. And of course this quite dangerous. After all there is plenty of software around that can modify xlsx files, but unless you know that a file does not contain formulas, you can never know if the values of formulas in the spreadsheet are still valid. Because, in the example above, there is nothing stopping you from modifying `A2` and `A3` in a way that the sum would no longer be `2`.

Comment: Oh and that's why I have added a [`showFormula`](https://janmarvin.github.io/openxlsx2/articles/openxlsx2_basic_manual.html#showformula---show-formulas-instead-of-results) option in `openxlsx2` to at least give a chance to see, if the value you are importing is from a formula or literally hard coded into a cell.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404270/run-vba-script-from-r)

After running the **saveWorkbook()** I ran the following chunk

```
#create an instance of excel   
xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")

#open the same file that you saved earlier with saveWorkbook() method
xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open("complete path to excel file")

#save the file and close it
xlWbk$Save()
xlWbk$Close()

#quit excel instance    
xlApp$Quit()
rm(xlWbk, xlApp)
```

You need to load **RDCOMClient** package before running the above chunk. After running this I got the updated values

```
read.xlsx("data/rough.xlsx", sheet = "Sheet1", rows = c(1:4), cols = c(2,3))

  a b
1 1 2
2 2 4
3 3 6
```

Basically all the modifications are done in **openxlsx** and **RDCOMClient** can be used to open and save the file instead of doing it manually. Hope this helps.

PS: I don't know much about VBA scripting in R and am looking for some resources. If you know of any, please share. Thank you!