# Extracting word from a file

Tags: java, file

Basically I have a file which consists of frequent Norwegian words. Words are stored in the following pattern.

```
1.  jeg 782578
2.  det 742951
3.  er 718645
4.  du 623395
5.  ikke 436196
```

From left to right: the first one is the list number, in the middle are the words I would like to extract and save, followed by the number count.  I want to extract the words in a document without the number list or the number count. Of course I can do this manually but the list is huge and it contains 5000 words. So I am looking for an efficient way to do this using Java.

Basically I can only read and write to a file in Java. So if you have any idea to accomplish this task, I would be grateful if you could share it with me.

Comment: If you know how to read a file, where is the problem?

Comment: `I would like to extract` extract what?

Comment: extract words that are in the middle

Comment: We do not have time to write code for you.Post your code here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick to doing something like this efficiently is to realize that you don't need to read the entire file into memory in order to manipulate it.  You can create a loop which reads one line of input at a time and does whatever work is required to create one line of output:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("output.txt");

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();     // read a line from the input file
        writer.println(line.split(" ")[1]);   // write a line to the output file
    }

    scanner.close();
    writer.close();
```

This will allow you make line-by-line modifications on a file of any size.

Comment: will try this one out.

Answer (score 0):

Well try something like this.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        new FileInputStream("pathOfYourTextFile/textFile.txt")));
PrintStream out = null;
while(true)
  {
   String line = br.readLine();
   if(line PrintStream out== null)
       break;
   else {
       String newline = line.replaceAll("-?\\d+.","").trim();
       out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("outputFile.txt"));
       out.println(newline);
     }
   } 
 out.close();
```

Atleast try something before you ask something

Answer (score -1):

Though you know programming don't always try to apply that knowlesge to every context.
You can simply replace all spaces with comma and save it as a .csv file. open it from excell or some spread sheet application. Delete the columns that you don't want. Save it back

Comment: well that possible can be posted as a comment

Comment: Its not me bro dont misunderstand

Answer (score -1):

(sorry cannot comment yet)

5000 is not that big. 
I assume you are on windows.

You can use an editor like Notepad++ to search and replace using regular expression (you would use regular expression in java too).
(here is one of the tutorials for Notepad++: http://markantoniou.blogspot.ca/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html )

Or as "Thusitha Thilina Dayaratn" suggested to import file to a Excel type of program. 
During the import, You just specify that the data is space/tab separated.

Comment: That works for a one time solution, but becomes more difficult if this is part of some automated process.

Comment: it's most efficient way. Unless you do it everyday. And it's fast. It much better approach than to learn java. And how difficult is to open a file in Excel and save it? You can probably use macros to automate the process. (example is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050505/way-to-run-excel-macros-from-command-line-or-batch-file)

Comment: `I am looking for an efficient way to do this using Java.` would lead me to assume their task requires them to use Java.