# How to explore an Excel COM AddIns and automate it

Tags: r, excel, vba, comaddin

I have a COM Add In, in excel from RIMES. It basically allows me to get data, there is a specific button refresh all data. I am loading the data in R and do calculus. I would like to avoid having to open and refresh the excel file before loading the data. In other words I would like something to "click on refresh all". I figured I could do a VBA script that would do that, however I cannot figure what are the functions embedded in the excel add-in. How can one "explore" the com addin ?

Thanks

Comment: you can try a decompiler such as http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx

Comment: That's a good idea. Any clue what kind of key words I should be looking for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to find a proper solution, turns out there are templates that are created form the COM ADD IN that uses the function refresh which is then available in VBA. One can then use a VB.script to create a way to compute everything without opening excel.

[How To Create a VB.Script (StackOverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050505/way-to-run-excel-macros-from-command-line-or-batch-file)

Cheers
R