# Can we convert PPT VBA Add-In code to console base?

Tags: vba, add-in, powerpoint

I have a requirement, PPT VBA add-in open-source  to run from console/command prompt.

Is it possible ?

[PPspliT](http://www.maxonthenet.altervista.org/ppsplit.php) is the open source project which needs to run from command prompt.

Thanks

Comment: PPspliT's author provides the full VBA source code. You could include this in e.g. a VB6 EXE that automates PPT using pretty much the same code.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg I talked with author too. But the source code is for GUI, so, how it will be compatible for CUI i.e console base ? Thanks

Comment: I just had a quick look at the source; it appears that you'd have to at a minimum modify it so that it works on the current presentation rather than current selection, then surround it with code that invokes PPT and opens the presentation you want to process.  Not simple, but a whole lot easier than reproducing all of Massimo's work yourself.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg, We do not want to open PPT, everything should happen in background. The console base app should take input as ppt file, split slide animation and save it. Same like PPspliT but everything should be done in background. Is it possible with this source code ? Thanks

Comment: No, it's not possible with this source code, though it's possible to automate PPT w/o PPT appearing in most cases. That requires an installed copy of PPT, of course.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg, I am sorry but do get it clearly. What does mean by `automate PPT w/o PPT appearing`, does this mean like, we can run from command line ?

Comment: Google terms like "automate powerpoint" for examples of "driving" powerpoint from another program. Your program can launch an instance of PowerPoint without making it visible if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute VBA directly from the command prompt; it is not the same as VBS.

You could however open Powerpoint from the command prompt and execute the required code that way.  [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2050505/8112776).