# VBS Script to execute VBA macro in external module

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I have two file:

**a VBS Script file**

The file is named `Trigger.vbs` and contain

```
Option Explicit

On Error Resume Next    
ExcelMacroExample

Sub ExcelMacroExample()     
  Dim xlApp 
  Dim xlBook 

  Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
  Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\MyPath\MsgBox.xltm", 0, True) 
  xlApp.Run "hello"
  xlApp.Quit 

  Set xlBook = Nothing 
  Set xlApp = Nothing     
End Sub
```

inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2056066/1008588) answer.

**an Excel file**

Named `MsgBox.xltm` and with the following Sub inside, written in VBA

```
Sub hello()
 MsgBox "Hello everybody"
End Sub
```

From `C:\MyPath`, when I double click on `Trigger.vbs` the macro is being executed.

---

**The question**

Now I would like to save the file Excel in XLSX format (so it can't contain any VBA code). Is it possibile to modify the VBS script including there the sub code or (better) to write the VBA code in a TXT file and tell the VBS script to open it and run into the Excel file?

Something like

```
Option Explicit

On Error Resume Next 
ExcelMacroExample

Sub ExcelMacroExample() 
  Dim xlApp 
  Dim xlBook 

  Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
  Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\MyPath\MsgBox.xltm", 0, True) 
  xlApp.Run (R:\MyPath\Module.txt)
  xlApp.Quit 

  Set xlBook = Nothing 
  Set xlApp = Nothing  
End Sub
```

where `R:\MyPath\Module.txt` contains the VBA code listed above.

Comment: I would place all the VBA code in an ADDIN workbook named `MsgBox.xlam` with all the code referring to the active workbook. Then simply open both workbooks with the VBS script and call the procedure.