# How to run a macro and copy a worksheet from Excel in R

Tags: r, xlsx, xlconnect, openxlsx

So my question can be divided into two parts: 
 1. How to run a macro in an **.xlsm** file in R. (The macro generates a chart in another sheet)
2. How to copy this generated chart into another workbook 
 
 I am trying to automate some procedural work and hence need to do the above operations in R. 
**EDIT** The chart generated is named **Chart1**

Comment: If you need to run a macro, you probably want to write a VBscript file, which you can call from R via `shell`. See this question for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050505/way-to-run-excel-macros-from-command-line-or-batch-file

Comment: The answer using `library(RDCOMClient)` is closest to what you describe. VBscript is probably more flexible and well documented.

Comment: @Mako212 But how do I access that chart object in R? I need to copy that generated chart into another workbook.