# Store a exel file in server and use its functions

Tags: excel, vba, server

I have an excel file that gets daily data from a website and I defined a macro for sending the new data to the database, my question is how can I do this without needing someone to run the script?
something like store an excel file in a web server ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Excel file on its own does nothing. It needs the Excel application installed to be of any use.

If you have access to a computer or server that has excel and is on all the time, you could create a scheduled task to run your macro at pre-defined times.

Using something like
[Way to run Excel macros from command line or batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050505/way-to-run-excel-macros-from-command-line-or-batch-file) to launch and run your macro.