# Error running Excel VBA text file output module from a batch file

Tags: excel, vba, batch-file

I am trying to run an Excel VBA macro from a batch file. I don't know much about either so I'm using one of the methods described in this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050505/way-to-run-excel-macros-from-command-line-or-batch-file). (Specifically I'm using the one suggested by @omegastripes.)

Everything works if I use the dummy macro used to illustrate the concept. However, when I use my actual macro, I get an error: "Method 'Worksheet' of object'_Global' failed." If I simplify by calling the macro every time the Workbook is opened, I still get the error. In that scenario, the macro works if I open the Workbook manually but I receive the same error if I open it with a (one line) batch file.

The macro I'm trying to run is just one that outputs a certain part of my Workbook to a text file. It's just a slight adaptation of [this article](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/write-data-to-text-file.html).

```
Sub GetClassList()

Dim ws As Worksheet, Rng As Range, TextFile As String, i As Integer, cellValue As Variant

Set ws = Worksheets(1)

TextFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Document Builders\Class List.txt"
Open TextFile For Output As #1

For i = 1 To ws.Range("O19").Value
    cellValue = ws.Range("R3:R10").Cells(i, 1).Value
    Print #1, cellValue
Next i

Close #1

End Sub
```

Comment: Just a guess but try `Set ws = Thisworkbook.Worksheets(1)`

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much. I guess the mechanism used to open the Workbook affects what is considered "global" and without the "Thisworkbook," the function Worksheets(1) was attached to the "global" object? (As I said, I have little experience with VBA.)